# Attaching images to posts manually (i.e. with custom code, without the use of an API)

Tags: php, images, attachments, mobile

I am working on mobile API for a WordPress site.
The API is written in PHP and provides methods actions such as creation of a post.

Now, I can create a post with one image (thumbnail) of the post.

How can I create post with multiple images, what records in what WP tables must I create to connect all this data?
I mean without using WP code, with pure PHP?

Comment: you can do this by creating image fiels in metabox and save its value in `wp_postmeta` table like metakey is image number and metavalue is image link or you can use multi image metabox plugin.

Comment: This is a potentially very complicated question. WordPress does a lot with image uploads, and the database structure for posts is also complicated. If you are going to duplicate that you are going to have to get to know the Core very well.

Answer (score 1):

Attachments are posts of type attachment with the parent field set to the post ID they are attached to.
The simplest way to see how this works is to look at the attachment functions in core code, [`/wp-includes/post.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post.php).